# Applications not showing up in Gnome 3 Activities > Search after .desktop configuration file created

Tags: gnome, .desktop, activities-overview

I usually place my local *.desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications`. Since very recently they do not show up anymore when I search for them after pressing <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key. They are all startable from the terminal though.

What can I do to make those programs accessible again from the dashboard?

The system is ubuntu *bionic* on *gnome3.*

Comment: As you, with 18.04, I put my *.desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications` and they are shown in gnome program list. My *.desktop files are not executable, just 'valid' desktop files...

Comment: Could you provide the content of a `.desktop` file which doesn't show up in Activities overview.

Comment: I think trusting it via nautilus double click was needed. ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've created a new Desktop Entry configuration file and the new application/link/directory doesn't show up in Activities search, your `.desktop` file is not configured, saved or located correctly.

**Desktop Entry configuration files must be:**
Saved as UTF-8
Saved in either;
`~/.local/share/applications` (single user: `/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/applications`)
or
`/usr/share/applications` (all users)
Contain the correct information
For applications the following minimal key=value pairs;

`Type=application
Name=name of application
Exec=absolute path to application`

By way of example, I downloaded the latest generic Firefox (firefox-60.0.1) to a USB drive and extracted it there.
I then created the following working minimal Desktop Entry configuration file called usb-firefox.desktop in folder ~/.local/share/applications;

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=USB Firefox
Exec=/media/user/usbDrive/firefox/firefox
Icon=/media/user/usbDrive/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
```

Gnome desktop entry specification from the developers can be found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/).

Comment: works with `~/.local/share/applications` too

Comment: No desktop file in /usr/share/applications is set as executable nor do any that are added have to be.

Comment: can you mention that you have to trust the desktop file using nautilus?

Comment: @ukos, after testing further, with a generic version of Firefox on USB, a Bash script and Tor, I didn't come across that trust step again, so I don't believe it's required if configuration is correct. If you can share the Desktop Entry file that you were using that wasn't showing up until you trusted via Nautilus I can take a look and see if I can replicate on my machine.

Comment: @Broadsworde it was probably some magic from within nautilus that updated to the correct path in my desktop file.

Comment: png images placed in `~/.local/share/icons` can be referenced to directly by name. 
In your example I would copy `default128.png` to `~/.local/share/icons/firefox-default128.png` and then the Icon tag in the desktop entry could be `Icon=firefox-default128`